# Publish free app but with monthly subscription

Tags: app-store, google-play-console

I wonder if there is any policy for free app publishing but with monthly charge, equal to Netflix and Spotify, both in PlayStore and AppStore.

Is there any specific policy for this case in the two stores mentioned?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Play it is actively encouraged as a way to monetize your app. And they provide APIs for doing it:

- [Overview documentation](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/earn/subscriptions) is here